# Could not find API14 Android 4.0 in SDK android in Android Studio to install

Tags: android

Is anybody could help me to find API14 Andriod 4.0 to install in my Android Studio? I only seen 8, 10, 15 and everything above that.

[image: Android Studio with SDK Manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the "Obsolete" checkbox in the SDK Manager window, and it should show up.